# UnityContainer is not disposed along all exception paths warning

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Could you please help me with a warning I recieve:

```
 Warning    CA2000  In method 'UnityConfig.UnityConfig()', object 'container' 
 is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on 
 object 'container' before all references to it are out of scope.
```

My code:

```
private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new 
Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });
```

And I have UnityWebApiActivator class with method:

```
public static void Shutdown()
{
    var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
    container.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981296/ca2000-dispose-object-before-losing-scope-building-unity-container